# get safari to not show broken image symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, safari

is there a way to get safari not to show the "broken image" symbol, when an image was not found? firefox does this by default.

i'd preferrably do this with css, but i think javascript will be the way to go... i am using jquery already, eg something like this would be great:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').broken().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/error/):

```
$("img").error(function(){
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is and event handler called onerror which you can add to the images:

```
<img src="image.png" onerror="this.style.visibility = 'hidden'" />
```